# AMP extraUrlParams sending data in-house

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to send analytics data inhouse and the server which I am trying to post data expects most of the data in number formats.
When I use extraUrlParams it always sends data as a string.

For example When we look at the payload currently we see
**{ wt: "83" }**

expected :
**{ wt : 83 }**

```
<script type="application/json">
{ 
   "requests":{ 
      "pageview":"example.com"
   },
   "triggers":{ 
      "trackPageview":{ 
         "on":"visible",
         "request":"pageview"
      }
   },
   "vars":{ 
      "dns":" ${navTiming(requestStart,responseStart)}"
   },
   "transport":{ 
      "beacon":false,
      "xhrpost":true,
      "image":false,
      "useBody":true
   },
   "extraUrlParams":{ 
      "wt":"${navTiming(requestStart,responseStart)}"
   }
}
</script>
```

Can someone please help me with this?